# Request - migration to php 7

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

I have an old function:

```
static public function Select($table, $terms)
    {
        if (trim($terms)=="")
            $request = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        else
            $request = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $terms";

        $res = mysql_query($request);
    }
```

But this does not work on the new version of PHP.

I know that `mysql_query` needs to be replaced by `mysqli_query`. 
However, for this you still need to connect to the database.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

But I am already connected in another file and do not want to do this here too.

Is there any way to implement this without connecting?

Comment: You could pass in your `$link` connection to your static `Select` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static public function Select($table, $terms)
    {
        **global $link;** //This way you're using the opened connection.
        if (trim($terms)=="")
            $request = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        else
            $request = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $terms";

```
    $res = **$link->query($request);** //This is the correct method to perform a query
}
```